# How to save pins to a map once app is closed

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, mkmapview

So in my app, the user drops pins on a map. What I don't know is how to save the pins in the app, so that when the user opens the app again and goes to the mapView, the pins that were dropped onto the map the last time the app was open are still on the map. Does anyone know how I am to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you got the Coordinates from that pins. You can first save them in a NSMutableArray. When you finished you could save this array in a NSKeyedArchive like this

```
NSMutableData *data         = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
NSKeyedArchiver *archiver   = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];

[archiver encodeObject:pinArray forKey:@"PinArray"];
[archiver finishEncoding];
[data writeToFile:archivePath atomically:YES];

BOOL success = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:pinArray toFile:archivePath];
```

When you launch your app, you can read this archive:

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:archivePath]) {


    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:archivePath];

    NSMutableArray *pinCollection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if (data){
        pinCollection = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
    }
    else pinCollection = nil;

    return pinCollection;

}
```

and position your pins on the map, according to the saved coordinates.

Comment: To add to your answer: [MKMapView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205-CH3-SW35) holds it's pins in `NSArray *annotations` property.

Comment: What is the archivePath? Is that the file where the data is stored?

Comment: Yes, it is the path of the file.